# The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Driver'

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run the following script from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
INSERT [Truck].[Driver] ([DriverId], [CorporationId], [DriverNumber], [Name], [PhoneNumber]) 
VALUES (N'b78f90a6-ed6d-4f0e-9f35-1f3e9c516ca9', N'0a48eeeb-37f6-44de-aff5-fe9107d821f5', N'12', N'Unknown', NULL)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
>   The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Driver', database 'SuburbanPortal2', schema 'Truck'.

I can manually add this in edit mode and I get no errors. I have every permission I can think of set for my users. This is a local database logging in as a local user that I'm testing some data on so I could care less about security.

But, here are the settings for the database for my user:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the ConnectionString? Also try SQL Profiler to so what happends.

Comment: You seem to have all the permissions..... on the `[dbo]` schema. But your table is in the `[Truck]` schema; do you have permissions on that schema as well??

Comment: Stupid question, but shouldn't it be INSERT INTO [Truck].[Driver]

Comment: @Andrew, the "INTO" is optional. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Well you learn something new every day then :)

Comment: @RalfdeKleine I don't have a connection string I am using Sql Server Management Studio. I am running it as a script from there.

Comment: @Andrew Also, this script was created by SSMS from another database with the same layout.

Comment: @marc_s I am the db owner, not sure if that makes a difference. I did check all of the schemas to be the owner and it shows a blue box, not sure if that exactly what it means without a checkbox but it will not let me check or uncheck them.

Comment: What about `INSERT [Dbo].[Driver] ([DriverId], ...` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why I had to do this, I'm not a Sql Server expert, but once I added myself to the master database I was able to execute the query. If anyone has an answer to that I'd like to know. Otherwise, after a bit I'm going to post this as my bewildered answer.

Comment: ErocM - did you move or copy this database from another server?  If so, the User SSIDs may be mangled.

Comment: Otherwise, a couple of things come to mind: 1) you are the developer, so you should be a member of sysadmin on your own PC.  Is that the case? 2) use CREATE ROLE Truck_Users AUTHORIZATION dbo; and then use sp_addrolemember to add your users to the ROLE.  Finally, use GRANT statements to give permissions to the ROLE, such as "GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::[Truck].[Driver] TO [Truck_Users];"  There are other permissions, such as "GRANT ALL" which gives everything to the role.

Comment: @Graeme Yes it was a restore from a backup copy. Put that as an answer and I'll upvote you please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- Use master
USE msdb;
go

-- Make database
CREATE DATABASE SuburbanPortal2;
go

-- Use the database
USE SuburbanPortal2;
GO

-- Make schema
CREATE SCHEMA Truck AUTHORIZATION dbo;
go

-- Make table
CREATE TABLE Truck.Driver
(
    [DriverId] uniqueidentifier,
    [CorporationId] uniqueidentifier,
    [DriverNumber] varchar(64),
    [Name] varchar(128),
    [PhoneNumber] varchar(12)
);

-- Add data
INSERT [Truck].[Driver] ([DriverId], [CorporationId], [DriverNumber], [Name], [PhoneNumber]) 
VALUES (N'b78f90a6-ed6d-4f0e-9f35-1f3e9c516ca9', N'0a48eeeb-37f6-44de-aff5-fe9107d821f5', N'12', N'Unknown', NULL);
GO
```

This code setups a sample database like you have.  I have no issues with the insert.

Who is the owner of the schema??

If you want to hide tables from one database group and another, add your user to the database group.

Make the database group the owner of the schema.  I think you might be having a schema ownership issue ...

Can you drill into database -> security -> schemas -> Truck, right click and show me the owner of the schema.  Please post image.

Also, remove all database permissions from the user except for db_owner.